# Javascript array math calculation results

Tags: javascript

I tried to resolve a challenge in javascript with arrays and when I try to stock result in an array they are different depending from the way I order the values when they are incremented the results are fine but when not the results are false

```
 function calcTotal() {
     bilArray = [124, 48, 268];
     var tipArray = [0.2, 0.15, 0.1];
     var totalArray = [];
     var calc = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < bilArray.length; i++) {
     if (bilArray[i] < 50) {
       calc = bilArray[i] * tipArray[0] + bilArray[0];

      } else if (bilArray[i] >= 50 && bilArray[i] < 200) {
       calc = bilArray[i] * tipArray[1] + bilArray[1];

     } else {
       calc = bilArray[i] * tipArray[2] + bilArray[2];
     }
      totalArray.push(calc);
     calc = 0;
  }
  console.log(totalArray);
  }
  calcTotal();
```

`Array(3) [ 66.6, 133.6, 294.8 ]` is the result when `bilArray`'s values are not ordered.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please clarify the question, it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: The order would have you get a different answer because you were being specific with what position of array value to pick from. You might need to explain better what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem in these lines:

```
calc = bilArray[i] * tipArray[0] + bilArray[0];
```

It should be related with the corresponding index.

Like this:

```
calc = bilArray[i] * tipArray[0] + bilArray[i];
```

Output:

```
[ 142.6, 57.6, 294.8 ]
```

Comment: pfffffff thank you very much i didn't see it
it works thank you